# Parameters in a function C++

Tags: c++, function, parameters, void

I'm using the Adafruit Motor Shield library v1 and making something with 4 motors in it and want to create a void function to call those motors to move

```
#include <AFMotor.h>
AF_DCMotor motor1(1);
AF_DCMotor motor2(2);

void motor1run() {
  motor1.run(FORWARD);
}

void motor2run() {
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
}
```

Instead of using different functions like I did above, Is there any way I could make the function take an int parameter x and using that run the xth motor?

```
#include <AFMotor.h>
AF_DCMotor motor1(1);
AF_DCMotor motor2(2);

void motorrun(x) {
  //runs the xth motor
}
```

Comment: How about using arrays?

Comment: What data type would the array be though

Comment: An array of pointers to whatever datatype `motor1` is.

Comment: An array of `AF_DCMotor`.

Answer (score 3):

So this is where you'd want to pass a pointer to the motor you're trying to run into the function.

```
void motorrun(AF_DCMotor *motor) {
  motor->run(FORWARD);
}

motorrun(&motor1);
motorrun(&motor2);
```

Comment: That's nice but it just moves the problem elsewhere. I actually want an int x to determine which motor moves, but in your code &motor1 isn't an integer. I've edited my post so its more clear I want an integer.

Answer (score 3):

You can also create an array for your objects:

```
// create AF_DCMotor array of size = 2. Assign object elements
AF_DCMotor motors[] = { AF_DCMotor(1), AF_DCMotor(2) };    

void motorrun (int i) {
    motors[i].run(FORWARD);
}


// trigger motors[0] to run
motorrun(0);

// trigger motors[1] to run
motorrun(1);
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Pointers and dynamic allocation not needed. Just plain `AF_DCMotor motors[] = { AF_DCMotor(1), AF_DCMotor(2) };`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude . That's simpler & better, modified my answer. Thanks for pointing out.